# Kafka Streams splitting the topolgy

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In my use case, i have below two option to build my kafka streams topology,

Topics where data streamed from:

- Topic A - 6 partitions
- Topic B - 6 partitions
- Topic C - 6 partitions

Intermediate Topic:

- Topic INTERMIDIATE - 6 partitions

### Option 1: with two topologies

```
Topology 1:
A.leftJoin(B).to(INTERMIDIATE)

Topology 2:
INTERMIDIATE.leftJoin(C).to(ResultTopic)
```

### Option 2: with single topology

```
A.leftJoin(B).leftJoin(C).to(ResultTopic)
```

I know both are resulting in same output, my question is,

Option 1 creates 12 tasks `max-partition(A, B) + max-partition(INTERMIDIATE,C)`

Option 2 creates just 6 tasks `max-partition(A, B, C)`

At high level, it looks like Option 2 is the best solution because I can just configure less threads to handle the tasks but in my use case i am making a big single topology,

```
A.leftJoin(B).leftJoin(C).leftJoin(D).leftJoin(E).leftJoin(F).to(ResultTopic)
```

In this case again just 6 tasks are created but the topics are more, is this a good solution to end up in less tasks by chaining the topics in a single topology?

Comment: Does Option 2 also require the intermediate topic? If not, that seems to be the main difference (with all side-effects this has, such as the ability to run either half of the topology independently and/or on different machines)

Comment: No. Option 2 does not have any intermediate topic as I am not performing any key changing operations in between.

Comment: Sounds like a classical tradeoff between parallelism and resource requirements -- if you have the additional topic you put more load on the network and the brokers. Don't think that there is a definite answer, but a tradeoff you need to decide on by yourself.